# WebApi: Attach MediaTypeFormatter to Controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I would like to remove `XmlFormatter` from global formatters in my project. I am doing this for it:

```
var formatters = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters;
formatters.Remove(formatters.XmlFormatter)
```

But in the same time I would like to have one controller which can return `xml` data type. Is it possible to decorate my controller with specific attribute or somehow attach XmlFormatter specifically to this controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a custom [System.Net.Http.Formatting.IContentNegotiator](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation) class and check the selected formatter into the `Negotiate` method.

```
public class ApplicationContentNegotiator : IContentNegotiator
{
    private readonly JsonMediaTypeFormatter _jsonFormatter;
    private readonly MediaTypeHeaderValue _jsonMediaType;

    private readonly XmlMediaTypeFormatter _xmlFormatter;
    private readonly MediaTypeHeaderValue _xmlMediaType;

    public static IContentNegotiator Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationContentNegotiator();
    }

    private ApplicationContentNegotiator()
    {
        _jsonFormatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();
        _jsonMediaType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");

        _xmlFormatter = new XmlMediaTypeFormatter();
        _xmlMediaType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/xml");
    }

    public ContentNegotiationResult Negotiate(Type type, HttpRequestMessage request, IEnumerable<MediaTypeFormatter> formatters)
    {
        var controller = new DefaultHttpControllerSelector(request.GetConfiguration()).SelectController(request);
        if (controller.ControllerName == "MyController")
            return new ContentNegotiationResult(_xmlFormatter, _xmlMediaType);

        return new ContentNegotiationResult(_jsonFormatter, _jsonMediaType);
    }
}
```

And then replacing your `IContentNegotiator` implementation service into `HttpConfiguration` object

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IContentNegotiator), ApplicationContentNegotiator.Create());
```

Comment: Thank you Alberto, nice solution. But we decided to use another approach.

Comment: @IvanKononenko What approach? :)